# Mysql msi installation for windows 10 x64, change installation folder?

Tags: mysql, windows, path, windows-installer

As the title describes, I run the MSI installation, but Im not being able to change the install directory, I need to change it because my C:\ disk is a 60gb ssd and I only want to use it for the OS.

Theres a way to change the installation path?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In theory this should work:

```
msiexec /i "Path To MSI" INSTALLDIR="D:\New\Installation\Directory" /qb
```

however if that doesn't work then try:

```
msiexec /i "Path To MSI" TARGETDIR="D:\New\Installation\Directory" /qb
```

/qb = basic interface.  You can also try /qn for a silent install.

http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/FAQFilesInstallDirs.htm

Answer (score 0):

***MySql***: I don't really know what installer you are using, but a quick peek at the simplest one I could find, seems to indicate that the installation location is defined by `INSTALLLOCATION` and there is another location called `DATALOCATION`.

If `TARGETDIR` or `INSTALLDIR` did not work (they might), then you could try setting those two location properties as well. Something like this:

```
msiexec /i MySetup.msi INSTALLLOCATION="D:\MySqlBins" DATALOCATION="D:\MySqlData" /qb
```

---

***SSD Disk Cleanup Tips***: Also want to let you know about this answer which tries to provide a list of ideas for how to deal with very small SSD disks (60GB is a challenge for a developer PC though - sorry to state the obvious): [VS 2017 Installation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49347375/vs-2017-installation-failed/49347648#49347648).