# How to burn Visual Studio 2015 offline installer into 2 DVDs?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-installer, dvd-burning

My hard-disk is nearly full, I need to backup the Visual Studio offline installer into 2 DVDs. (each can store ~4.3GB).

The Visual Studio 2015 installer's size is 7.22GB.
[image: SplitVisualStudio2015Installer.jpg]
The installer data is inside the packages folder, I need to determine how can I split this folder. Here is the package inside the packages folder:

```
packages\64bitPrereq
packages\adal_Sql2016_amd64_chs
packages\adal_Sql2016_amd64_cht
packages\adal_Sql2016_amd64_deu
packages\adal_Sql2016_amd64_enu
packages\adal_Sql2016_amd64_esn
packages\adal_Sql2016_amd64_fra
packages\adal_Sql2016_amd64_ita
packages\adal_Sql2016_amd64_jpn
packages\adal_Sql2016_amd64_kor
packages\adal_Sql2016_amd64_ptb
packages\adal_Sql2016_amd64_rus
packages\adal_Sql2016_x86_chs
packages\adal_Sql2016_x86_cht
packages\adal_Sql2016_x86_deu
packages\adal_Sql2016_x86_enu
packages\adal_Sql2016_x86_esn
packages\adal_Sql2016_x86_fra
packages\adal_Sql2016_x86_ita
packages\adal_Sql2016_x86_jpn
packages\adal_Sql2016_x86_kor
packages\adal_Sql2016_x86_ptb
packages\adal_Sql2016_x86_rus
packages\AppInsights
packages\AuthenticationConnectedServices
packages\BehaviorsXamlPhoneSDK
packages\BehaviorsXamlSDK
packages\Blend_Core
packages\Blend_LP
packages\BlendSDKForWindowsPhone80
packages\BlendSL5SDK
packages\BlendWPF45SDK
packages\BlendWPF4SDK
packages\Bliss_Core
packages\Bliss_LP
packages\BuildTools_MSBuild_amd64
packages\BuildTools_MSBuild_x86
packages\BuildTools_MSBuildDev12_amd64
packages\BuildTools_MSBuildDev12_x86
packages\BuildTools_MSBuildNuGet
packages\BuildTools_MSBuildResMsi_amd64
packages\BuildTools_MSBuildResMsi_x86
packages\ClientDiagnostics_CORE
packages\ClientDiagnostics_RES
packages\ClientDiagnosticsAR_CORE
packages\ClientDiagnosticsAR_RES
packages\ClientDiagnosticsXD_CORE
packages\ClientDiagnosticsXD_RES
packages\communitycore
packages\communitylp
packages\ConnectedServices
packages\CoreCon
packages\CoreConD12
packages\CT
packages\DiagnosticsHub_CORE
packages\DiagnosticsHub_CORECOLLECTION
packages\DiagnosticsHub_RES
packages\Dotfuscator
packages\dotNetFramework
packages\EFTools
packages\EmulatorWP81
packages\enterprisecore
packages\enterpriselp
packages\EspC
packages\EspCD11
packages\fsharp
packages\GraphicsDebuggerx86
packages\Help
packages\HelpLP
packages\IISExpress
packages\IntelliTraceCore
packages\IntelliTraceFrontEnd
packages\IntelliTraceLocCore
packages\IntelliTraceLocFrontEnd
packages\JavaScript_LanguageService
packages\JavaScript_ProjectSystem
packages\KB2882822
packages\kb3022398
packages\lightswitchcore
packages\lightswitchcoreres
packages\lightswitchv5sdk
packages\lightswitchv5tools
packages\lightswitchv5toolsres
packages\localdbMsu
packages\MDDFirstParty
packages\MobileServicesConnectedServices
packages\MobileTools
packages\MobileTools_EmulatorWP81
packages\netfx_451mtpack
packages\netfx_451mtpackcore
packages\netfx_452mtpack
packages\netfx_46mtpack
packages\netfx_netcoresdk50
packages\NetFxDTP
packages\O365APITools
packages\Patch
packages\PerfDebuggerWebViewsCore
packages\PerfDebuggerWebViewsLoc
packages\PerformanceCollectionTools
packages\PerfTools_CORE
packages\PerfTools_RES
packages\PhoneAddon
packages\PhoneAddonD12
packages\PortableLibrary
packages\PreEmptive
packages\premiumcore
packages\premiumlp
packages\professionalcore
packages\professionallp
packages\Reporting Services
packages\RIA
packages\sdk_tools35
packages\sdk_tools451
packages\sdk_tools46
packages\SharedManagementObjects_amd64
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_amd64_chs
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_amd64_cht
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_amd64_deu
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_amd64_enu
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_amd64_esn
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_amd64_fra
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_amd64_ita
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_amd64_jpn
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_amd64_kor
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_amd64_ptb
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_amd64_rus
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_x86_chs
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_x86_cht
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_x86_deu
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_x86_enu
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_x86_esn
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_x86_fra
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_x86_ita
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_x86_jpn
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_x86_kor
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_x86_ptb
packages\SharedManagementObjects_Sql2016_x86_rus
packages\SharedManagementObjects_x86
packages\Silverlight
packages\sptools
packages\sptoolsDependencies
packages\SpToolsLP
packages\sptoolsVSIXInstaller
packages\sqlcmdlnutils_amd64
packages\sqlcmdlnutils_x86
packages\SqlDom_amd64
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_amd64_chs
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_amd64_cht
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_amd64_deu
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_amd64_enu
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_amd64_esn
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_amd64_fra
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_amd64_ita
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_amd64_jpn
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_amd64_kor
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_amd64_ptb
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_amd64_rus
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_x86_chs
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_x86_cht
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_x86_deu
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_x86_enu
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_x86_esn
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_x86_fra
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_x86_ita
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_x86_jpn
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_x86_kor
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_x86_ptb
packages\SqlDom_Sql2016_x86_rus
packages\SqlDom_x86
packages\sqllocaldb_amd64
packages\sqllocaldb_Sql2016_amd64_chs
packages\sqllocaldb_Sql2016_amd64_cht
packages\sqllocaldb_Sql2016_amd64_deu
packages\sqllocaldb_Sql2016_amd64_enu
packages\sqllocaldb_Sql2016_amd64_esn
packages\sqllocaldb_Sql2016_amd64_fra
packages\sqllocaldb_Sql2016_amd64_ita
packages\sqllocaldb_Sql2016_amd64_jpn
packages\sqllocaldb_Sql2016_amd64_kor
packages\sqllocaldb_Sql2016_amd64_ptb
packages\sqllocaldb_Sql2016_amd64_rus
packages\sqllocaldb_x86
packages\sqlncli_amd64
packages\sqlncli_x86
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_amd64_chs
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_amd64_cht
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_amd64_deu
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_amd64_enu
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_amd64_esn
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_amd64_fra
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_amd64_ita
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_amd64_jpn
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_amd64_kor
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_amd64_ptb
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_amd64_rus
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_amd64_chs
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_amd64_cht
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_amd64_deu
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_amd64_enu
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_amd64_esn
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_amd64_fra
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_amd64_ita
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_amd64_jpn
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_amd64_kor
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_amd64_ptb
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_amd64_rus
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_x86_chs
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_x86_cht
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_x86_deu
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_x86_enu
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_x86_esn
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_x86_fra
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_x86_ita
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_x86_jpn
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_x86_kor
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_x86_ptb
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_Sql2016_x86_rus
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_x86_chs
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_x86_cht
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_x86_deu
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_x86_enu
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_x86_esn
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_x86_fra
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_x86_ita
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_x86_jpn
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_x86_kor
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_x86_ptb
packages\SQLSysClrTypes_x86_rus
packages\SSCE40
packages\SSDT
packages\SSDT_enu
packages\SSDT_Sql2016
packages\SSDT_Sql2016_chs
packages\SSDT_Sql2016_cht
packages\SSDT_Sql2016_deu
packages\SSDT_Sql2016_enu
packages\SSDT_Sql2016_esn
packages\SSDT_Sql2016_fra
packages\SSDT_Sql2016_ita
packages\SSDT_Sql2016_jpn
packages\SSDT_Sql2016_kor
packages\SSDT_Sql2016_ptb
packages\SSDT_Sql2016_rus
packages\StorageConnectedServices
packages\TeamExplorer
packages\TestAgentService
packages\TestTools
packages\TFSOfficeIntegration
packages\TFSStoryboarding
packages\TSqlLanguageService
packages\TSqlLanguageService_Sql2016__chs
packages\TSqlLanguageService_Sql2016__cht
packages\TSqlLanguageService_Sql2016__deu
packages\TSqlLanguageService_Sql2016__enu
packages\TSqlLanguageService_Sql2016__esn
packages\TSqlLanguageService_Sql2016__fra
packages\TSqlLanguageService_Sql2016__ita
packages\TSqlLanguageService_Sql2016__jpn
packages\TSqlLanguageService_Sql2016__kor
packages\TSqlLanguageService_Sql2016__ptb
packages\TSqlLanguageService_Sql2016__rus
packages\TypeScript
packages\UnitTest
packages\UnitTestRes
packages\update3notification
packages\vc_compilerCore
packages\vc_compilercore_wp80
packages\vc_compilerCore86
packages\vc_compilerCore86D11
packages\vc_compilercore86res
packages\vc_compilerCore86ResD11
packages\vc_compilerCoreD11
packages\vc_compilercoreres
packages\vc_compilercoreres_wp80
packages\vc_compilerCoreResD11
packages\vc_compilerx64arm
packages\vc_CompilerX64ArmRes
packages\vc_compilerx64nat
packages\vc_CompilerX64NatRes
packages\vc_compilerx64x86
packages\vc_CompilerX64X86Res
packages\vc_kb2829760
packages\vc_librarycore
packages\vc_librarycore_wp80
packages\vc_librarycore86
packages\vc_libraryCore86D11
packages\vc_libraryCoreD11
packages\vcRedistD11
packages\vcRedistD12
packages\vcRedistD14
packages\vcRuntimeDebug_amd64
packages\vcRuntimeDebug_x86
packages\vcRuntimeDebugD11_amd64
packages\vcRuntimeDebugD11_x86
packages\Verification
packages\VisualC_D14
packages\VS_Clean
packages\vs_devenv
packages\vs_devenvLP
packages\vs_enterprise
packages\vs_minshellcore
packages\vs_minshellinterop
packages\vs_minshellres
packages\vs_RoslynLanguageServices
packages\vs_RoslynLanguageServicesResMsi
packages\vs_testToolsTeamExplorerClient
packages\vs_testToolsTeamExplorerClientLP
packages\vs_vshub
packages\VSGraphics
packages\vsgraphics_helper
packages\vssdk_vscore
packages\VSTemplates
packages\VSTO
packages\VSTODT_x64
packages\VSTODT_x86
packages\VSTODTLP_x64
packages\VSTODTLP_x86
packages\vsupdate_core
packages\vsupdate_KB3022398
packages\VSUPreReq
packages\WcfDataServices
packages\WebDeploy
packages\Win10_UniversalCRTSDK
packages\Win81_SDK
packages\Win81DevTools
packages\Win81Graphics
packages\Win8DevTools
packages\Windows
packages\Windows_Espc
packages\Windows_SDK
packages\WindowsPhone81SDK
packages\WindowsPhone81VHD
packages\WinLibJS_CORE
packages\WPT
packages\XPSupport
packages\ModernBlend_finalizer.msi
packages\ultimate_finalizer.msi
packages\VSGraphics_VSGA_finalizer.msi
```

It's best if the following checked features is in the first DVD
[image: VisualStudioFeature.jpg]

If I can't determine how to choose packages for each DVD, then I guess the final solution is splitting the installer with zip then just burn the zip parts to DVDs (the final solution is not good because if I use this, I can't install the software directly from DVDs).

Comment: use 1 double layer DVD

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I miss the point entirely, but why can't you just use a **high capacity thumb drive** instead? Maybe you need a **cheaper media that is more secure** than that? Or you just don't have a thumb drive available? How about an SD-card? From your phone? (might not be allowed to connect to your corporate PC - definitely check). Or phone by USB? Bluetooth?

Also, here is a long list of some acceptable and several marginal ways of [**freeing up more disk space on your SSD system disk**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49347375/vs-2017-installation-failed#49347648). **Space reclaiming options** **`2`**, **`18`**, **`19`** may be the most well known and effective ones, but there is a whole long list.

Comment: mmm... you miss the point :p For example, I had a small pan but I caught a big fish, I couldn't just buy a bigger pan to fry the big fish, I must think of a way to fry the big fist on the small pan. Ignore the freeing up disk space problem, focus the split DVDs problem.