# Install .msi on usb stick

Tags: windows-installer, command-prompt

I have recently been trying to install the Core Game Engine on a USB stick because I have run out of space on my C drive. When I run the CoreLauncherInstall.exe and set the USB stick as the installation directory, I get the error: "*Installation directory must be on a local hard drive*". Any ideas for a workaround? So far I have tried extracting the `.msi` file from the `.exe` and running: `msiexec /i "d:\CoreLauncherInstall.msi" WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH="1"` however I still got the "*Installation directory must be on a local hard drive*" error when I set the installation directory to my USB stick.
`

Comment: Did you manage to reclaim some disk space of significance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Restriction***: That sounds like a built-in restriction in the MSI itself - potentially it is part of the Windows Installer Engine - I am not 100% sure. It is either built into the engine or a launch condition most likely implemented as a custom action inside the MSI itself (in the latter case it could then potentially be disabled using a transform).

***Youtube.com***: A video on youtube suggests running your setup using an elevated **`cmd.exe`** command prompt: [Fix "installation directory must be on a local hard drive"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1WTBW-KbXA).

***Clear Space***: However, you should not install this to your USB drive if it is a core engine. Components like that should be installed locally on your system drive for many reasons.
What you need is to clean out your drive, and I believe you already know that is the right call and don't want to hear it? :-). In any case, here is some advice to create some space:

- [**How to clear out some free space on your drive**](https://serverfault.com/questions/642177/how-can-i-eliminate-the-huge-cached-msi-files-in-c-windows-installer/642178#642178).
- [Long and babbly edition of how to clear out free space on your drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49347375/vs-2017-installation-failed/49347648#49347648).

There are many suggestions in there that you can try. A few that might really help. The first in line:

**`Microsoft's Disk Cleanup Tool`**. Purge Windows Update files & more.

- <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + Tap <kbd>R</kbd>, type **`cleanmgr.exe`** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Select system drive and press <kbd>OK</kbd>
- Now click **`Clean up System Files`** then select system drive and press <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Inspect the various options for what you can clean. Do not clean the "Downloads" folder if you get that option (it has been removed in newer Windows 10 versions, but you might use a downstream version). This option clears out your Downloads folder and could zap downloaded source code and similar...

Please read all options carefully and get that backup done? I am always hesitant with suggestions such as these. Most are trivial, but things can always end badly. For example people who try to delete vendor recovery partitions off laptop drives and get a non-booting system. Deleting such a hidden drive can create a lot of extra space though.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response and links! I'll see if I can free up some space somewhere.

Comment: How big is your drive? There are some limits on 120GB drives and smaller in terms of what you can do that is effective.

Comment: My USB drive is 32 GB. I decided on using a spare USB enabled HDD I found to install the MSI. I guess since the HDD is a disk drive the PC thought it was a local hard drive.